# Class members of a native object accessed using JNI change value unexpectedly

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a Java project in which I use some C++ code using JNI.
I encountered a weird problem.

I have a class that looks more or less like so:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    MyType* _p;

public:
    MyClass();

    virtual ~MyClass();

    void myFunc();
};
```

And:

```
MyClass::MyClass() : _p(NULL) {
    // _p's value here is indeed NULL (0)
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {

}

void MyClass::myFunc() {
    if (_p != NULL) {
        delete _p;
    }

    _p = new MyType();
}
```

No other function but `myFunc` touches `_p`, and for some reason, even after initializing it to `NULL`, when calling `myFunc` for the first time, `_p` has some garbage value in it and the function attempts to delete it.

The ctor of `MyClass` is called using JNI, and `myFunc` is too called using JNI, on a separate occasion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're calling myFunc on a valid instance of MyClass? Can you run it trough a debugger via ndk-gdb?

Comment: By the way, it's always safe to delete a null pointer, so your null check is redundant.

Comment: How exactly are you calling the constructor using JNI? How do you arrange that the call to `myFunc` from JNI refers to the same C++ object you constructed?